# Rails 4.1 tests return undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec

I'm working through the treehouse tutorials using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.5 and I got into an issue with my tests in the auth tutorial.

The tutorial says that this code should pass:

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to todo_lists_path
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password"
        render action: 'new'
    end
end
```

Here are my tests:

```
describe "POST 'create'" do

        context "with correct credentials" do
            let!(:user){
                User.create(
                first_name: "Jason", 
                last_name: "Seifer", 
                email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", 
                password: "teamtreehouse1234",
                password_confirmation:"teamtreehouse1234")}

          it "redirects to the todo list path" do
            post :create, email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", password: "treehouse1234"
            expect(response).to be_redirect
            expect(response).to redirect_to(todo_lists_path)
          end

          it "finds the user" do
            expect(User).to receive(:find_by).with({email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com"}).and_return(user)
            post :create, email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", password: "treehouse1234"
          end

          it "authenticates the user" do
            User.stub(:find_by).and_return(user)
            expect(user).to receive(:authenticate)
            post :create, email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", password: "treehouse1234"
         end

          it "sets the user id in the session" do
            post :create, email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", password: "treehouse1234"
            expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user.id)
          end

          it "sets the flash success messagge" do
            post :create, email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", password: "treehouse1234"
            expect(flash[:success]).to eq("Thanks for logging in!")
          end
        end

        context "with blank credentials" do
          it "renders the new template" do
            post :create
            expect(response).to render_template('new')
          end
          it "sets the flash error messagge" do
            post :create, email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", password: "treehouse1234"
            expect(flash[:error]).to eq("There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password")
          end
        end

        context "with incorrect credentials" do
          let!(:user){
            User.create(
            first_name: "Jason", 
            last_name: "Seifer", 
            email: "jason@teamtreehouse.com", 
            password: "teamtreehouse1234",
            password_confirmation:"teamtreehouse1234")}

          it "renders the new template" do
            post :create, email: user.email, password: "fuckingpassword"
            expect(response).to render_template('new')
          end
          it "sets the flash error messagge" do
            post :create, email: user.email, password: "fuckingpassword"
            expect(flash[:error]).to eq("There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password")
          end
       end
end
```

That gives me the error `` undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass ``the only way I've made the tests pass is with the following:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

        if user.nil?
            flash[:error] = "There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password"
            render action: 'new'
        else
            user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            flash[:success] = "Thanks for logging in!"
            redirect_to todo_lists_path
        end 
    end
end
```

I know it's ugly but it worked, right to the point that I needed to test whether it denied authentication with the right user but the wrong password. The tests returned two errors:

```
1) UserSessionsController POST 'create' with incorrect credentials renders the new template
Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template('new')
   expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>

2) UserSessionsController POST 'create' with incorrect credentials sets the flash error messagge
Failure/Error: expect(flash[:error]).to eq("There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password")
expected: "There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password"
        got: nil
```

The first example failed because for what ever reason(maybe rspec) the if clause doesn't handle user.authenticate(params[:password]) because it returns a hash.

let it be noted that the following code works in bin/rails console :

```
> user = User.create(first_name:"John", last_name: "Doe", email: "jon.doe@me.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
> user.save
> if user && user.authenticate("password")
> puts "wawa"
> end
wawa
=> nil
```

I've tried refactoring the create method so that it authenticates on assignment to no avail:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]).authenticate(params[:password])

    if user.nil? || user == false
        flash[:error] = "There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password"
        render action: 'new'
    else
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for logging in!"
        redirect_to todo_lists_path
    end 
  end
```

I get `` undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass `` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug it wasn't in the logic it was in the tests, I was testing the password with incorrect credentials `treehouse123` instead of the one that was being created in my user `teamtreehouse123`.

Inspiration came in this debugging code:

```
    def create
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      if (user.nil? == false) 
        if user.authenticate(params[:password]) 
          puts user.authenticate(params[:password])
          puts "NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Batman!"
          session[:user_id] = user.id
          flash[:success] = "Thanks for logging in!"
          redirect_to todo_lists_path
        else 
          puts user.authenticate(params[:password])
          puts "waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka waka"
          flash[:error] = "There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password"
          render action: "new"
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error logging in. Please check your email and password"
        render action: "new"
      end
    end
```

`user.authenticate(params[:password])` always returned false, regardless of what I did.

The Treehouse code is correct, but I'm changing all occurrences of `teamtreehouse123` to `password`.

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass` is a classic Rails error.

The error is **never** in the `authenticate` method. It's always in the part before it.

Here, you have an error on `User.find_by(email: params[:email])`. This part of code returns `nil` in this case. So Rails is trying to execute `nil.authenticate(params[:password])`.

Please check your `params[:email]` value or your list of users.

Comment: I'm sure that's true but I haven't the faintest idea how to fix it. The thing is that my tests require an empty user for them to pass, and not even sending empty strings allow authenticate to work.

Comment: My code fails on if user.authenticate(params[:password]), it doesn't authenticate the user even when I've checked that user.nil? == false.